# QuickBooks API POST using Google Apps Script

Tags: post, google-apps-script, quickbooks-online

Does anyone have a working example of doing a POST to the QuickBooks API using Google Apps Script?

I'm trying to create an estimate using the QuickBooks API, however although the request body below works in the API explorer, from within Apps Script I get:

```
Error: Fetch failed, code: 400, message: {"Fault":{"Error":[{"Message":"Request has invalid or unsupported property","Detail":"Property Name:Unrecognized token 'Line': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')\n specified is unsupported or invalid","code":"2010"}],"type":"ValidationFault"},"time":"2016-08-02T09:51:28.917-07:00"} (line 195, file "Tests")
```

But I can't see why the API expects a boolean rather than the "Line" key.

This is how I define it as a POST payload in the code:

```
  var payload = {

    "Line": [
      {
        "Id": "3",
        "LineNum": 1,
        "Amount": 10,
        "DetailType": "SalesItemLineDetail",
        "SalesItemLineDetail": {
          "ItemRef": {
            "value": "2",
            "name": "Hours"
          },
          "UnitPrice": 10,
          "Qty": 2
        }
      },
      {
        "Amount": 10,
        "DetailType": "SubTotalLineDetail",
        "SubTotalLineDetail": {}
      }
    ],    
    "TxnTaxDetail": {
      "TotalTax": 0
    },
    "CustomerRef": {
      "value": "1",
      "name": "Mr  Blobby"
    },
    "CustomerMemo": {
      "value": "Thank you for your business and have a great day!"
    },
    "TotalAmt": 31.5,
    "ApplyTaxAfterDiscount": false,
    "PrintStatus": "NeedToPrint",
    "EmailStatus": "NotSet",
  }

  var companyId = PropertiesService
    .getUserProperties()
    .getProperty('QuickBooks.companyId')

  var url = 'https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/' + companyId + '/estimate'

  var options = {
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    },
    contentType: 'application/json',
    method: 'post',
    payload: payload,
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
  }

  var service = OAuth1_.getService();

  var response = service.fetch(url, options)
```

Comment: Can you show us the full call you made to UrlFetchApp?

Comment: +Dimu Designs - Added fetch

Answer (score 0):

You need to stringify the whole payload before passing it to the OAuth.fetch() call.

So

```
var payload = JSON.stringify({
  "Line": [
    {
      "Id": "3",
      .
      .
})
```